# Inverse of operator with kernel $K(x,y)=(1-xy)^{-1}$ on the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $$f(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{g(y)}{1-xy}dy.$$ Is there a $G(x,y)$ such that 
$$g(y)=\int G(x,y)f(x)dx?$$ (with some integration contour)

Answer (score 1):

So we have an operator $T$ bringing $g(x)$ into $(Tg)(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{g(y)}{1-xy}\,dy$ and we want an explicit representation for $T^{-1}$, fine. We may notice that $[x^n](Tg)(x)=\int_{0}^{1}y^n g(y)\,dy$, so the reconstruction of $g$ from $Tg$ is equivalent to solving the [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem). Under suitable regularity assumptions,  it can be done through the Laplace or [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform).

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the relation between the transforms you mention and the kernel $(1-xy)^{-1}$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @thedude: the $n$-th derivative of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{g(y)}{1-xy}\,dy$ at the origin is $n!\int_{0}^{1}y^n g(y)\,dy$, so the derivatives at the origin of $Tg$ are the moments of $g$.

Comment: I am just exploiting $\frac{1}{1-xy}=1+x y+x^2 y^2+\ldots$.

Comment: Yes, the part about moments I get, but where is the Laplace transform?

Comment: The (inverse) Laplace transform is exactly the tool allowing to go in the opposite direction, from the moments to the function.

Comment: But the inverse Laplace transform is the inverse of the Laplace transform, of course, while my transform is not the Laplace transform. So how can my inverse be the Laplace inverse? Sorry if I am being obtuse

Comment: In order to go from $Tg$ to $g$ (with $T$ being *your* transform), you need to reconstruct a function from its moments. That's what the inverse Laplace transform does.